# In PHP, what happens when you enter down inside a string definition from within the text editor?

Tags: php, mysql

Say you define a string this way:

$string = "This is

a string."

Can someone explain if there are consequences or odd behaviors as a result of doing this?  I used it in a MYSQL query without any ill effects.  I find it easier to write some strings this way to make viewing easier inside the text editor.  Is there a better practice?

Comment: This is perfectly valid in PHP and preferred method for better code readability. Only place this can have an odd behavior is where you don't need carriage return/blank line in your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's valid syntax (well, except you're missing a semicolon on the end), but if you are wanting to do multiple lines like that, I would suggest you instead use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/heredoc) syntax